# Exception while using closeOnCompletion()

Tags: java, h2

Namaskaram,

I am using H2 database for my Java based Desktop POS (Point of Sale) application. I am getting the below exception, when I try to use the method closeOnCompletion() for my Statement and PreparedStatement objects.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.closeOnCompletion()V

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The default H2 jar file is currently not compiled for Java 7. [Java 7 compatibility is disabled in the source code](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcStatement.java#929) currently.

You can enable it yourself by compiling H2 yourself (using `./build.sh jar`).

Please note the current implementation of `closeOnCompletion` is a no-op.